# How can I change datetime field to date field?

Tags: migrations, datetime

I have a Drupal site successfully migrated from Drupal 6 to Drupal 10. Some date content type fields were changed during migration from date format to datetime format by mistake. Drupal's admin > manage fields doesn't allow me to change the field format, because there is node data stored in the field. Is there any way to convert them back to date forma without losing the stored data?

Answer (score 0):

One way to change a field format is to backup content of database tables `node__field_[your_field_name]` and `node_revision__field_[your_field_name]` and flush them. This step will allow admin user(s) to change the field format, or to remove the field completely and create it again with the same system name. Then you can import the tables back to the database.